# Error when running msbuild pipeline for deploying SSRS reports on private agent

Tags: reporting-services, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy SSRS reports using msbuild task on private agent of Azure Devops - I'm able to deploy these reports manually from VS which means I do have access to the Report Server however build pipeline gives following error. Can someone please advise?

**Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.**

This report server is installed in integrated mode and I have tried using hosted agent. Even though the hosted agent doesn't give any error but it still doesn't proceed with the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> Error when running msbuild pipeline for deploying SSRS reports on private agent

According to the error message, it seems you are the old version of MSBuild--the one that ships with the .NET Framework--from the command line. Microsoft is now releasing MSBuild as part of Visual Studio itself and also as a separate installer:

[MSBuild is now part of Visual Studio!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/)

So, first, try to add `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0` to the MSBuild command line to check if it works for you.

Note: The value is based on the Visual Studio version installed on your private agent. Visual Studio 2015 is `14.0`, Visual Studio 2017 is `15.0`, Visual Studio 2019 is `16.0`.

Besides, if above not help. You should make sure you have installed the Visual Studio on the private agent and the file `Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets` is exists under the MSBuild folder, for exanple, Visual Studio 2017:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Reporting Services
```

Finally, when you use the MSBuild task to deploy SSRS reports, you should select the correct version MSBuild:

[image]

You should make sure the version you selected is the version you installed on the private agent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have access to private agent so I will have to rely on different team to check some of the stuff you have mentioned. However I have another question - if private agent has MS Build installed, can it help in deploying (including shared data sources) to Report Server or just compilation ? I'm also wondering if MSBuild would just do the build or even deloy